# Script Shell to change name of all my files but with specifics rules

Tags: shell, parsing, mv

I have a car and my audio post only read music with a specific order.

I have a big list of music, and I want to change every justanexemple.mp3  on 001|justanexemple.mp3 and the next one "i love stackoverflow.mp3" on "002|i love stackoverflow"

Also, we get one limit is when I'm on the 009|music.mp3, and I want the next one like this 010|music.mp3

I also get a problem is I have some music with space like this "I like turtles.mp3"
so the command mv doesn’t function...

So I coded something like this

```
    #!/bin/sh                                                                                   

counter=001

for file in `ls -1 *.mp3 | sort -t. -k 2n` 
do   
newname=$counter'|'.$file   
if [ $file != $newname ]
   then mv $file $newname   
fi   
counter=`expr $counter + 1`   
counter="00${counter}" 
echo $counter done
```

but is not working great...

my music list is something like that :

```
> Kario & Yaret - Somos Lokos (Prod. By Las Ovejas Negras & Gaby.mp3
> Dj_Foxx-T_-_An_Sé_an_Nonm_(feat._Pompis)_-_.mp3
> Harry_Toddler_-_Draw_Mi_Table_wegotitfirst_com.mp3 Kario & Yaret Ft.mp3
> Mc Cassidy Ft. Polakan Y Delirious - Bad Boy.mp3
```

...

Comment: You'll want to avoid using `for` loops with file names, and don't use `ls` to generate the list: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. [Don't parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)
2. Don't use string concatenation to format numbers.  Use `printf`
3. Quote your variables

Your script can be written as:

```
c=0
for i in *.mp3; do
  c=$((c+1))
  pref=$(printf "%03d" $c)
  echo "$i" "${pref}|$i"
done
```

If the output seems good, replace `echo` with `mv` to perform the actual rename.